# How to re-run tests failed in a subdirectory using Cucumber-JVM

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

We like to organise our test sets into subdirectories (we have a lot of them) and run either a single feature or a subdirectory.

If I run a single feature,

```
java -classpath <OUR classpath> cucumber.api.cli.Main' \
 --plugin rerun:rerun.txt \
 --glue skeleton.dm \
 tmp/web_baseline/lesson1/bulb_c_voltage_explain_q2.feature'
```

then the system generates a rerun file with a path to that feature:

```
tmp/web_baseline/lesson1/bulb_c_voltage_explain_q2.feature:8
```

And then I can re-run using `@rerun.txt`

But when I run using the whole directory

```
java -classpath <OUR classpath> cucumber.api.cli.Main' \
 --plugin rerun:rerun.txt \
 --glue skeleton.dm \
 tmp/web_baseline/lesson1/'
```

Then the system finds all files in the directory, but generates a re-run file without paths:

```
bulb_only_explain_q6.feature:8 short_circuit_build.feature:8 ...
```

As a result, because the subdirectory is not on a classpath, it cannot find the feature files for rerun and fails. I cannot put all subdirectories on the classpath because we have quite a few nested ones.

Is there some parameter that I am missing that would allow me to make this work?

Comment: Please consider adding more relevant tags (e.g. [tag:java]) so that your question gets more attention.

Comment: Does this [issue](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/958) help?